# Huge or infinite response with WireMock

Tags: wiremock

I would like to test our app using a HTTP client with
a huge amount of data. Is it possible to create an infinite or several gigabytes length
output with WireMock without allocating a byte array or String with that size?

As far as I see [`ResponseDefinitionBuilder` has three `withBody*` methods](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/client/ResponseDefinitionBuilder.java#L100):

- `public ResponseDefinitionBuilder withBodyFile(String fileName)`
- `public ResponseDefinitionBuilder withBody(String body)`
- `public ResponseDefinitionBuilder withBody(byte[] body)`

I have tried `withBodyFile("/dev/zero")` but I got the following exception:

```
WARN (ServletHandler.java:628) - /test.txt
com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.security.NotAuthorisedException: Access to file /dev/zero is not permitted
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.AbstractFileSource.assertFilePathIsUnderRoot(AbstractFileSource.java:160)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.AbstractFileSource.getBinaryFileNamed(AbstractFileSource.java:45)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.StubResponseRenderer.renderDirectly(StubResponseRenderer.java:115)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.StubResponseRenderer.buildResponse(StubResponseRenderer.java:64)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.StubResponseRenderer.render(StubResponseRenderer.java:56)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.AbstractRequestHandler.handle(AbstractRequestHandler.java:50)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.servlet.WireMockHandlerDispatchingServlet.service(WireMockHandlerDispatchingServlet.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    ...
```

The other two require a huge in-memory array or string which I also would like to avoid.

I've also checked the [`Fault` enum](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/http/Fault.java) but it does not seem extendable.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you saw the file security error is that WireMock will only read files under its configured file root, so setting up a symlink might work.

Failing that, just creating a very large file would do the trick, and won't consume a lot of memory as body files are streamed.

Comment: Thanks! Writing a file to `/tmp` also returns the exception above. Could you write a PoC, please? I would like to avoid putting a 2GB file into the source tree (although it could be ignored by git).

Comment: As I mentioned, WireMock will only serve files that are under your configured root directory, so you either need to create that under `/tmp` and configure WM to point to it, or symlink the large file from `/tmp` under your `__files` dir.

Comment: ^ The answer `__files` works! I tried to access files outside of that directory and failed. That was the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Wiremock Version 2.15.0 you could define file stubs like that

stubFor(any(urlPathEqualTo(url))
.withQueryParam(xxxx)
.withQueryParam(xxxx)
.willReturn(aResponse()
.withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
.withBodyFile("/xservice/file.json")));
where /xservice/file.json was under /src/test/resources/__files/xservice/file.json

Upgrading to Version 2.17.0 and checking the implementation of com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.AbstractSourceFile I can see that the same test will fail with

com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.security.NotAuthorisedException: Access to file /xservice/
If I strip the / from /xservice so that we define the stub like

stubFor(any(urlPathEqualTo(url))
.withQueryParam(xxxx)
.withQueryParam(xxxx)
.willReturn(aResponse()
.withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
.withBodyFile("xservice/file.json")));